# Struggling with function types

Tags: typescript

I am new to TypeScript and was playing around with function types on the TS playground and I ran into a weird situation:

```
const func: (...args: any[]) => void = (x: number, ...args: any[]): void => {
    x.toFixed(); // No TS error here either
};

func('hello'); // No TS error, can be called with a string even though first param is a number
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMAXDAFAOmwQwE4DmEaOYAngNoC6AlDALwB8MAbiAJYAmDGAHmmAQBbAEYBTPABoY2TPiIly1GmjZcGzAN4AoGHpi9MUEADF2vMZ3Q0A3DAD09mADkQMACoBlGBLwg8MAAWEmI+7FDBeNoAvjba2ojI6ADkwQA2aSDJtg5Orh7evv7SwKQw4jClGZYwAO7hgTA4MNB47GAEPixiYDARIAgEjXDseNAwAA74OEIw7BBNMIKiEkA)

How is it that we can pass in a string value as the first argument even though the function takes a number. The way I see it, we should have gotten a TS error either when assigning the function to that type or when calling it with a string. What am I missing here?

Any guidance will be very much appreciated.

Comment: [The `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) is intentionally unsafe and lets you do things that would otherwise be considered an error.  If you changed it to `(...args: unknown[]) => void` instead like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbl52w) shows, you'd see an error as expected. Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, I think I get it. Using 'any' basically disables the type errors.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have explicitly mentioned that `func` has the type of `(...args: any[]) => void` you are not getting any error because `func` accepts `any[]` as its argument. Types from the function params are ignored, as another example let's create two number constants where one is having an explicit type of `number` and the other one doesn't:

```
const a: number = 1; // a is number
const b = 1; // b is 1
```

If you remove the explicit type then everything works as expected:

```
const func = (x: number, ...args: any[]): void => {
  x.toFixed();
};

func('hello'); // expected error
```

Answer (score 0):

[The `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) is intentionally [unsound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness), which means that it will allow you to do things which are not known to be safe.  This is often useful, because sometimes the compiler complains about perfectly valid code; in order to suppress such errors, the language lets you use some "escape hatches" from type checking, like the `any` type, or like [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  But of course if you use these escape hatches, the burden of verifying correctness has been transferred away from the compiler and onto you. Because if you make a mistake, the compiler can't catch it.

The type `(...args: any[]) => void` is one such use.  It means that the compiler will not try to type check the arguments to the function when it's called, or to try to type check the parameters of the function when it's implemented.  It's definitely true that assigning `(x: number, ...args: any[]) => { x.toFixed() }` to `func` is unsafe, but you (unintentionally) *asked* for it to be allowed because `any` is assignable to `number`.

If you wanted something to be more strictly checked, you could use [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) instead of `any`:

```
const func: (...args: unknown[]) => void = (x: number, ...args: any[]): void => {
    //~~~~ <-- error! unknown is not assignable to number
    x.toFixed();
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMAXDAFAOmwQwE4DmEaSA1mCAO5gDaAugJQwC8AfDAG4gCWAJixgAeaMAgC2AIwCmeADQxsmfETQ4wAT3oM0XPi3YBvAFAxTMAPTmAfjaswAPAFpHMCTn44IEbgTBipYLDSwDgIEFIwZBTUMNwQMBSwnt6+OBIANhFQIAni0ngmZoKY2QBi3IJSvOgMANxGAL71RojI6ADkABZS6ekg7XUW5jAAcjkAKgDKMDJ4IHIwIWCuESG9VTCU3FCdMDgw0HjcYAQzHAEwOyAIBLtw3HjQMAAO+DhisfH7opIyQA)